# How do I make values update automatically if user clicks on another option?

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have a currency converter which works fine, but when the user selects a different currency, I want the calculation to happen automatically without them having to press enter. I thought it would require adding an event listener for a click but I can't seem to get it to work.

I've tried setting up an event listener but I think I'm referencing the wrong things.

```js
function init() {


const data = [
    {
        currency: 'btc',
        we_buy: 0.58,
        we_sell: 0.77,
        img_path: 'img/bitcoin.svg',
        icon: 'fab fa-btc'
    },
    {
        currency: 'usd',
        we_buy: 0.67,
        we_sell: 0.82,
        img_path: 'img/united-states.svg',
        icon: 'fas fa-dollar-sign'
    },
    {
        currency: 'gbp',
        we_buy: 0.50,
        we_sell: 0.68,
        img_path: 'img/united-kingdom.svg',
        icon: 'fas fa-pound-sign'
    },
    {
        currency: 'eur',
        we_buy: 0.59,
        we_sell: 0.76,
        img_path: 'img/european-union.svg',
        icon: 'fas fa-euro-sign'
    }
];


// Image container

const imagesContainer = document.getElementById("currencies");
imagesContainer.addEventListener('click', output_we_sell);
let selectedCurrency = null;
var selectCurrency = function (index) {
    const element = data[index];
    selectedCurrency = data[index];
    document.getElementById("currency-selected").innerHTML = `Currency selected: ${element.currency}`;
    document.getElementById("data_icon").className = element.icon; 
};


(() => {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        imagesContainer.innerHTML += `<div class="currency" onclick=selectCurrency(${i})><img id=${i} src=${data[i].img_path}></div>`;
    }
    selectCurrency(0);
    const amount = document.getElementById("amount");
    amount.onkeyup = () => {
        const output_we_buy = document.getElementById("output_we_buy");
        const output_we_sell = document.getElementById("output_we_sell");
        if (amount.value === '') {
            output_we_buy.innerHTML = 0;
            output_we_sell.innerHTML = 0;
            return;
        }
        if (!isNaN(amount.value)) {
            output_we_buy.innerHTML = `${(+amount.value * selectedCurrency.we_buy).toFixed(2)}`;
            output_we_sell.innerHTML = `${(+amount.value * selectedCurrency.we_sell).toFixed(2)}`;
        }
    }
}

)();

}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init)
```

```html
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="currencies-container">
            <div class="currencies" id="currencies">

            </div>
            <div class="currency-selected" id="currency-selected">
                No currency selected.
            </div>

            <div class="output">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" maxlength="5" pattern="[0-9]{4}" min="0" max="99999"class="form-control" aria-label="Amount of GP in Millions" placeholder="Amount of GP (in millions)"
                            id="amount">
                        <div class="input-group-append">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i id="data_icon"></i></span>
                            <span class="input-group-text" id="output_we_buy">.00</span>
                            <span class="input-group-text" id="output_we_sell">.00</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I expect the script to generate a new result if the user clicks another currency, rather than having to press enter.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](/help/mcve).

Comment: That is the minimum code to reproduce the error? The error occurs after the user has typed into the input box. If they click another currency the value remains the same from the previous currency until they press enter

Comment: The code you put in your question has no data.  It does not run as-is.  People would need to go to extra effort just to figure out how to get to a state where they can reproduce your problem.

Comment: What do you mean it has no data? The data is stored within the Javascript, everything is generated into the HTML from there.

Comment: It would be generated into the HTML if you posted something that actually ran, but you didn't.   What you posted required the reader to do some amount of work before they could reproduce your issue.  If you had done the work yourself, you would have seen at least one thing that might be contributing.

Comment: I took the exact code posted here into codepen and it worked just fine, so I'm not really sure what you're trying to get at?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194630/discussion-between-tibrogargan-and-zee).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, you've stored anonymous function inside the value `amount.onkeyup()` at the bottom, outside the scope of `selectCurrency()`, so `selectCurrency()` cannot access it. You'll want to raise the scope, and then use it in the places you want.

```
// made function originally in amount.onkeyup have a greater scope
const calculate = () => {
    const output_we_buy = document.getElementById("output_we_buy");
    const output_we_sell = document.getElementById("output_we_sell");
    if (amount.value === '') {
        output_we_buy.innerHTML = 0;
        output_we_sell.innerHTML = 0;
        return;
    }
    if (!isNaN(amount.value)) {
        output_we_buy.innerHTML = `${(+amount.value * selectedCurrency.we_buy).toFixed(2)}`;
        output_we_sell.innerHTML = `${(+amount.value * selectedCurrency.we_sell).toFixed(2)}`;
    }
}
// ...
var selectCurrency = function (index) {
    const element = data[index];
    selectedCurrency = data[index];
    document.getElementById("currency-selected").innerHTML = `Currency selected: ${element.currency}`;
    document.getElementById("data_icon").className = element.icon;
    calculate(); // Added calculate here
};

// ...
(() => {
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        imagesContainer.innerHTML += `<div class="currency" onclick=selectCurrency(${i})><img id=${i} src=${data[i].img_path}></div>`;
    }
    selectCurrency(0);
    const amount = document.getElementById("amount");
    amount.onkeyup = calculate; // Changed this to use the calculate function
}
```